# Is it possible to add lazy loading to ASP.NET MVC + React.js application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I have ASP.NET application. Each View looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

where `bundle.js`is built using webpack from React.js code. Rounting is implemented using Controllers. Is it possible to add lazy-loading to this application?
I've found that React 16.6+ supports component-based code-splitting and lazy-loading has been added via React.lazy() and React.Suspense. But the features are not available for server-side rendering. Is it possible to say that the described application is server-side rendering?

Comment: Could you find a solution to this?